# reorganize matrix or data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R where the rows are gene names and the columns are gene ontology IDs, so that it looks like this:

```
Gene     V1    V2    V3      
Gene 1   GO1   GO2   GO3      
Gene 2   GO2   
Gene 3   GO2   GO3
```

I'm trying to rearrange it so that the rows are unique gene ontology IDs, and each gene that matches those IDs is in a separate column in that row:

```
GO    V1     V2     V3
GO1   Gene1 
GO2   Gene1  Gene2  Gene 3
GO3   Gene1  Gene3
```

I looked into reshape2, but it doesn't seem to be useful for this kind of reorganization. Is there a simple way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `melt/dcast`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), reshape into 'long' format with `melt` (from `data.table`), remove the blank rows based on 'GO', and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "Gene", value.name = "GO")[GO != ""], 
        GO ~ paste0("V", rowid(variable)), value.var = "Gene", fill="")
#    GO     V1     V2     V3
#1: GO1 Gene 1              
#2: GO2 Gene 1 Gene 2 Gene 3
#3: GO3 Gene 1 Gene 3
```

Comment: why `paste0("V", rowid(variable))` works, but not `variable` in the dcast formula? Thanks

Comment: @Sathish I think there are dupes there when I tried with `variable`.